# Zend Framework: Need help setting up Routing

Tags: zend-framework

how do i set up routing as follows

**these work with the standard routing**

```
/posts            => index action (listing)
/posts/view       => view action (individual post)
/posts/add        => add action
/posts/edit       => edit action
```

**what abt these?**

`/posts` can by filtered based on 1 or more query strings, in any order. eg.

/posts/tagged/tag1
/posts/tagged/tag1/timeframe/1w        => fyi. 1w means 1 week
/posts/timeframe/1w/tagged/tag1        => can be in any order
/posts/sortby/dtposted                 => more options maybe added

how can i handle these? i tried

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    'posts/*',
    array(
        'controller' => 'posts',
        'action' => 'index'
    )
);
$router->addRoute('postsIndex', $route);
```

but of cos, all routes to `posts/*` goes to the index controller. not what i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to use a route for those url's if your using proper naming conventions it should naturally.

```
class PostsController extends Zend_Controller_Action{
    public function viewAction(){
    }
    public function editAction(){
    }
    public function addAction(){
    }
    public function indexAction(){
    }
}
```

I suggest going back to basics and learning how controllers models and views work in the zend framework before trying to understand routing :)